# Does method invoke cost remain constant with more interface implementions

Tags: java, c#, performance

Lets say we have an interface "ISomething" with the method "DoSomething".
And we create multiple classes that implement it. Example 5/10/100/1000 new class definitions.

will iterating a List < ISomething > and calling DoSomething() take the same amount of time, regardless of #unique classes added to the list. Assumption that list contains the same number of objects. Comparison list of different types vs list of same type.

Essentially I am asking if an interface method call is always a "Constant" runtime cost, or it depends on # unique types behind it.

Why am I asking this? I need to realise how interface works behinds the scenes to not trigger unexpected overhead.

**Edit:** Can I make the question a little harder ?
Lets consider the opposite scenario, we now have only 1 class but N interfaces it implements(ISomething1...N). Is the performance the same regardless on the #interfaces that it implements. Lets say that most of the interfaces end up pointing to the same method.

**Edit2:** adjan's answer raises another potential issue: 
he said that c# generates one v-table per interface => all its methods cost O(1).

Lets consider the following scenario. 
A vertical inheritance chain: A0 extends A1 extends A2 ... extends AN.
All these classes we construct them with no variables inside.
We just created a performance bug.

A0.method() costs O(N).
I0.method() costs O(1).

If interfaces can do the job with a constant overhead, why pay variable cost if someone abuses the inheritance mechanism and creates a vertical tree branch of depth N.

Does A0 virtual method cost O(N) ? What about its constructor, or its destructor, are we 100% safe to assume that it takes constant runtime cost. Regarding the constructor, a call to A0's constructor triggers A1's parameter-less constructor, thus the invocation chain continues... therefore O(N) cost.

Comment: Regarding your edit: It does not matter. See my answer.

Comment: About your second edit: There is no invocation chain. No matter how deep the inheritance tree is, invocation will be always O(1). There is no search for the right pointer to the v-table. The pointer is already determined when you declare the variable.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/8529958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling an interface method, a so called v-table is used to determine the memory address of the called method. Each type has its own v-table that contains pointers to each implemented method, and every object of that type has a pointer to its type's v-table. Thus, during method invocation, there is no branching or searching for the right memory address, since the pointers will always uniquely point to the right v-table and method addresses.

Also see this diagram:

[image]

---

**Edit:** Regarding your second question. There is no difference. A call to a virtual method costs always the same, because you're only accessing the same number of pointers:

```
interface I1
{
   void DoIt();
}


interface I2
{
   void DoIt();
}


class A : I1, I2
{
   public void DoIt()
   {
      // do sth
   }
}

// Note: All v-tables point to the same implementation in A

I1 test1 = new A();
test1.DoIt(); // => lookup in I1's v-table

I2 test2 = (I2)test1;
test2.DoIt(); // => Lookup in I2's v-table

A a = (A)test2;
a.DoIt(); // => Lookup in A's v-table
```

Image source: https://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/com-interception/vtable.png

Answer (score 6):

First off; this kind of premature optimization is crazy. The overhead involved with invoking through an interface just isn't significant enough to matter.

That said, mixed types will not have a runtime impact *unless* you are dealing with branch prediction. (See [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)).

The reason for this is that you are incurring the overhead of invoking through a virtual function pointer table regardless of whether it picks the same one over and over or not. Really; its just not something you need to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference.

Languages like java and C# implement virtual method calls in a way which is quite similar to the way C++ does it.  Roughly speaking, each class has a virtual method table, which is an array of pointers to methods.  There is one entry in this table for each virtual method defined by the class or interface.  A virtual method call simply consists of picking a pointer from a specific index within that table and calling the function pointed by it. It makes no difference whether you have a single implementation or a hundred implementations. The runtime cost is as constant as it gets.

There is no operation that I can think of whose runtime complexity is in any way a function of the number of existing class implementations in the (Java or .Net) virtual machine.